# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Microsoft Account OAuth2 sign-on is returning "error=access_denied" when a valid domain is used instead of localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented a very simple OAuth2 sign-on for *Microsoft* and *Google* accounts (See: *Startup.Auth.cs* and *AccountController.cs*) and I am facing an issue for authenticate when I am using the *Microsoft* authentication with a valid domain (e.g.: **_http://mydomain.ddns.net/IRIS/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FIRIS%2F**):

- *error=access_denied*

Note that if I try to authenticate using the *localhost* instead of *mydomain.ddns.net* (e.g.: **_http://localhost/IRIS/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FIRIS%2F**) the *Microsoft* authentication works perfect!

Other important info is that for both cases, *localhost* and *mydomain.ddns.net*, the *Google* authentication is working without any issue!

From [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList) I could not identify any issue once that **_http://mydomain.ddns.net/IRIS/signin-microsoft** and **_http://localhost/IRIS/signin-microsoft** are registered as *Redirect URIs*

Some of you have faced a similar problem? I really appreciate if any of you help me for fixing this issue :)

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount;
using Owin;

namespace IRIS
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var cookieAuthenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions { ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login") };
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieAuthenticationOptions);
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(cookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType);
            //https://console.developers.google.com/project/iris-985/apiui/credential
            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions { ClientId = "<MyGoogleClientId>", ClientSecret = "<MyGoogleClientSecret>" });
            //https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList
            app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions { ClientId = "<MyMicrosoftClientId>", ClientSecret = "<MyMicrosoftClientSecret>", Scope = { "wl.basic", "wl.emails" } });
        }
    }
}
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace IRIS.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None)] //Evita o seguinte erro de login: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376800/the-back-button-and-the-anti-forgery-token
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult GoogleLogin(string returnUrl)
        {
            return new ChallengeResult("Google", Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult MicrosoftLogin(string returnUrl)
        {
            return new ChallengeResult("Microsoft", Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string error, string returnUrl)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["account"].Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            string[] outputParameters = new string[4];
            if ((error != "access_denied") && (Models.Data.Firebird.ExecuteProcedure("I_LOGIN", new string[] { System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email).Value }, outputParameters)))
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["account"]["error"] = outputParameters[0];
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["account"]["userID"] = outputParameters[1];
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["account"]["userFirstName"] = outputParameters[2];
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["account"]["userFullName"] = outputParameters[3];
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["account"]["userEmail"] = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["account"].Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            }
            return outputParameters[0] != null && outputParameters[0] == "0" ? RedirectToLocal(returnUrl) : RedirectToAction("Logout", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Logout(string returnUrl)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
            return returnUrl == null ? RedirectToAction("Index", "Home") : RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        #region Helpers
        private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        internal class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
        {
            public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
            {
                LoginProvider = provider;
                RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            }

            public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
            public string RedirectUri { get; set; }

            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
                context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Had any luck with this?

Comment: Hi Stefan, yes! Microsoft requires https OAuth2 sign-on. In another words, it works perfect for _https://mydomain.ddns.net/IRIS/